# The application Ecliplise can't open - Mac OS - Yosemite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I'm running OSX Yosemite, and I just downloaded latest adt bundle and my java version is

> java version "1.8.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_25-b17) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

,at the first when I tried to open eclipse , he asks me to install Java 6 http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
, but after the installtion it gives me this message  "The application Ecliplise can't opened"

Please tell me what to do, Thanks

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using ?

Comment: The latest one https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip @StackFlowed

Comment: Can you let me know a name from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Name

Comment: @StackFlowed Eclipse 3.8 for Mac OS X, so I think it's Juno

Comment: Upgrade it to the luna or more & it should work fine.